# How can I use datetimepicker in Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

How can I use a datetimepicker knowing that I use bootstrap4 and most of the solutions I found on the internet didn't work well and `input type="datetime"` feature is no longer supported by most browsers

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
       

 <input id="id" name="datetime" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker"  value="">

<script>
$(function () {
             $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
         });
  
      
</script>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, how is this problem related to Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of deprecated datetime you can use

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

more details you can find on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Answer (score -1):

if you'r looking for better datepicker than basic . I will suggest you to use [flatpikr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) , you can do much more using that  like you can pick date between range, format date ,enable or disable certain date, enable or disable given range of date and it has better ui than basic calendar
. check out it's [examples](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/).

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that using another datepicker is a viable solution?